# WCF- Differences between proxy object, service object and normal class object

Tags: wcf

what is difference between the WCF proxy object and the normal class object and service object (actual WCF service object) in detail ?

Is there any functionality which can be performed on class object and which cannot beperformed on WCF proxy.

Comment: 100% duplicate of http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/1000dfa7-f822-4a82-a1e8-5f1b027f11cf/what-is-differnce-between-wcf-proxy-and-wcf-service-object-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your client proxy is a usual .NET class which is inhereted from ServiceModel.ClientBase class. When you create proxy, .NET environment just adds the logic of consuming your service methods so as if they are locals. Proxy contains the dublicates of your service methods and some constructors, where you can define bindings, endpoints and so on. When you call method in proxy - it opens the chanel, creates a message and sends it to the server. That is what proxy does. It does not contais the logic of your methods.

You service class - is also a usual .NET class, marked with some special service attributes. When you start your service, the .NET environment begins to listen for the messages, sent by clients. And when it recives such messages - it unpacks them, creates the instance of your service class (or uses created already) and executes the method. Then the result is send back in return message.

So client proxy does not contains any logic - it is used only to send messages with info of **what method it called and what params are used**. The service class contains **all the logic of your methods**.